# How to have a UITableView link to another UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am currently making an app using swift that has information about cars.
I am using an `UITableView` for makes, models, years.

What I want to know is if can I have an `UITableView` linked to another `UITableView` depending on user input, for example:

tableview 1 (makes)

- Audi
- Honda

tableview 2 (Models)

- Audi -> A1, A2, A3........
- Honda -> Civic, Jazz...

tableview 3 (years)

- Audi -> A3 -> 2005,2006,2007.....
- Honda -> Civic -> 2005,2006,2007.....

> **Code for tableview 1**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.Makes = [Make(name: "Audi"),Make(name: "Nissan"),Make(name: "Fiat"),Make(name: "Ford"),Make(name: "Honda"),Make(name: "Mercedes-Benz"),Make(name: "Lexus"),Make(name: "BMW"),Make(name: "Vauxhall"),Make(name: "VW")]
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.Makes.count

}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    var make = Makes[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = make.name
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I don't understand ? Why not have have organized you data , FirsTableView for Makes, SecondTableView for Models in based cell selected for user in the first SecondTableView and a third for the Year based in the model selected in the SecondTableView?

Answer (score 1):

1.- Organise your data in a good manner, maybe a graph, a tree, or simply lists relating all of your data.

2.- For simplicity makes functions that will give you corresponding data to each tableview.
Lets say:

```
func getModels(make: Makes) -> [Model]
func getYears(model: Model) -> [Years]
```

or simply

```
func getModels(make: String) -> [String]
func getYears(model: String) -> [String]
```

also, some helper functions that will allow you to implement any data structure behind, just like, for example:

`func getMaker(int:Int) -> Maker?` or `func getMaker(int: Int) -> String?`

3.- You must keep in memory which of your possible makers and models have been selected, for now, keep it like:

```
var selectedMaker: String?
var selectedModel: String?
```

4.- I assume you will have all your `UITableViews` at the same `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`, so you will need to decide corresponding data to show to every one. 
For this you will need to differentiate each one, how is up to show, with tags, instance equality, etc. I suggest for later readability and facility of use to end up having a function that will return a number? maybe, corresponding to the tableview. For this explanation sake, lets call it `func whichTableIsThis(tableView: UITableView) -> Int?`

5.- Your delegates should work different for everyone of those tableviews. Here we will be using our brand new function that must return 1, 2 or 3 ..nil if this tableview is not one of those. :)

```
extension YourViewControlerWithTableViews: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //I'm assuming you will have only one cell, lets call it `AttributesTableViewCell`
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourCellName", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AttributesTableViewCell
    cell.attributeValue.text = ""
    if let tableNumber = whichTableIsThis(tableView) {
     //here you will be checking for every of your tree cases, for this example I will check just for Models
       //OK, so tableNumber returned 2
     if tableNumber == 2 && selectedMaker != nil{
        let value = getModels(selectedMaker!)[indexPath.row]
        cell.attributeValue.text = value
       } 
      //...
    }
    return cell
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let tableNumber = whichTableIsThis(tableView) {
       //here you will be checking for every of your tree cases, for this example I will check just for Models
       //OK, so tableNumber returned 2
       if tableNumber == 2 && selectedMaker != nil{
         return getModels(selectedMaker!).count
       }  
       //...
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   if let tableNumber = whichTableIsThis(tableView) {
       //here you will be checking for every of your tree cases, for this example I will check just for Maker
       //OK, so tableNumber returned 1
       if tableNumber == 1 {
         selectedMaker = getMaker(indexPath.row)
         //Here you must refresh data for your next tables in hierarchy, to allow them to refresh with new data
         selectedModel = nil
         selectedYear = nil
         tableview2.reloadData()
         tableview3.reloadData()
       }  
       //...
    }
 }
}
```

And..that should be all. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much will update tomorrow after i have inputed the code

Comment: @Alexh The issue with point 4 (reloading the tableView instead of pushing a detail view controller onto the navigation controller stack) is that there's no intuitive way to pop back to the previous level.  Stick to familiar, expected push/pop behavior that all users would know.

Comment: @PetahChristian the applications can be many and as of the creative point of view, infinites. Alexh does not specify if is for some kind of game, or if it's a general/commercial app. As what you are stating about point 4, I'm agree that if the only purpose of the view is to show this data, is easier for the user's brain to find itself looking to one step at the time. But again, all of this depends on the application's designer intentions. The user can always select another **Maker** and all data will be refreshed.

Comment: I agree that there are infinite creative possibilities.  But it generally means writing a lot more code to then make your custom UI adaptive, instead of taking advantage of the SDK's built-in adaptability. iOS 9 will bring split-screen multitasking and it would be built-in by using Master-Detail with `UISplitViewController`. If Alex isn't familiar with how to do this, he might not understand the trade off in using an overloaded view controller delegate for multiple table views.

Answer (score 0):

This approach of drilling down to see more details is very common, and Xcode even provides a template to illustrate this, called Master-Detail.

The way this works is when you select a row in the first (or Master) tableView, it performs a `showDetail` segue to the second (or detail) tableViewController.

In `prepareForSegue`, you would get the indexPath of the selected row, and pass the make to the detail (destination) view controller.  That view controller would then show all the models for that make of car.

You would use the same process in the detail tableView to pass a specific model to the a third tableViewController to see all years for that make and model.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, 
            sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            Let make = Makes[indexPath.row]

            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController 
    as UINavigationController).topViewController 
        as! DetailViewController

            controller.detailItem = make
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = 
    splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

The Master-Detail template provides other benefits, such as Adaptive UI.  For example, on an iPad or iPhone 6 Plus, the user could choose to see both the master and detail views in a split view.

Comment: Thank you will be looking in to it tomorrow

Comment: @Alexh You can check out [this free app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/messiah-bible-prophecies-about/id951349672?mt=8&at=1010l3f4) to get a feel for how 3 levels of information can be navigated.  If that works the way you want, you can find [the source code on GitHub](https://github.com/PetahChristian/TheMessiah).  It uses segues to link the three tableViews as I explained.  Let me know if you have any questions!